# Iin file you're reading from, get the position of where a regex match is found

Tags: regex, vb.net

I've been reading a file into a string and then using regex to match certain data and then using regex.nextmatch. Is there any way I can find out what the position in the file is of where the match was found, e.g. position 10768?

Comment: What do you mean by position? You want the line number or?...Any way, what have you tried so far? Where is the problem?

Comment: Is that not within match.index ?

Comment: Thank you Alex! That's just want I needed. Time to parse links! :)